# PHP file renamed to JPG and uploaded to server a threat?

Tags: php, linux, security, ubuntu

We have a server that has been compromised that is running WordPress and Magento and is running them on about 5 domains all on the same server.

The hacker has been uploading there malicious scripts through all the file-system in hundreds of locations.  It is a nightmare at this stage and I am still unable to find the entry point.

I did just notice that one of our AJAX image upload fields allows me to rename a PHP file as a .jpg and upload the file to the server.

When I access the PHP .jpg file in the browser is serves a broken image.

So I am not sure if the hacker would be able to upload a PHP file here and access it as a PHP file or if it would just serve it as a broken image fore like it did for me in the browser?

Any ideas on how much of a security threat this could be?  Could it potentially be my entry point where hacker gained initial access?  Or is the fact it serves as a broken image instead of processing the PHP file when I load in my browser mean that its somewhat secure?

Any help appreciated, thank you

Comment: unless you told your server that .jpg files should be run through php, it's totally harmless. Remember, there's no such thing as "php scripts". There's only files with php code blocks within them. If the file never gets near the php interpreter, the php code remains what it really is: plain text.

Comment: If the file is named `.jpg`, the server won't run the PHP code in it.

Comment: You're getting a broken image because it's just sending the PHP source code to the browser, and that's not a valid JPEG file.

Comment: Well, if you have something like a sql injection vulnerabilty or some other issue where user provided input is somehow used in commands, then certainly it is possible to somehow include that file. Then commands in there will get executed. But usually the attacks on wordpress are much more primitive. It all starts with the code itself being writable for the code itself which is what a typical wordpress installation looks like...

Answer (score 2):

Hard to say if the hacker has done something without actually checking what's there.

Regarding how to secure future image uploads I would advice using a function like `finfo` in PHP http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php to find if a file belongs to any of the approved mime types, which btw, you should restrict to only a limited type of image types.

Also you should consider not allowing the use of the original image, but instead an adjusted version of it, to avoid that users end up downloading huge images or things like that.

**Answer:**
Usually (depending on the web server configuration) no one can execute a PHP file if it has a different extension, they could have upload it, but they can't run it, at least in any common configuration.

So, in theory you should not have to worry for that specific thing, but do be worry that someone is spending time in trying to hack you and that means you should expend time protecting the site and server.

I would recommend searching for articles on how to protect your specific server and configuration and to make sure you update your software, OS and such to the latest security updates.

Comment: And how is this meant to be an answer to the question? It is just some general hints...

Comment: There, I highlighted where the actual answer is. But in general terms I try to understand the complete problem and try to answer not only to the question, but on how to handle him self on that situation. I guess then I should have being more limited to the question.

Comment: Sorry, but what you marked in your question as "answer" is wrong. I agree that "usually" such files should not get interpreted as code. But what is the worth of such a general statement? There are situations when this can happen. For an example see my comment above. Not that likely, not that common, but that is not the point. It is possible. So your answer is wrong. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Being able to upload a file with .jpeg file extension but PHP content is not a vulnerability in itself. However:

1. if the attacker is writing all over the file system you might have an upload function with a directory traversal vulnerability which will need fixing, ideally by not letting the uploader choose their own filename at all;
2. there are other problems to do with cross-site-scripting when you let users upload content to be served from the same hostname as the site;
3. it may be worth checking an uploaded file using something like [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) to ensure that you have a JPEG file and non-ridiculous dimensions, but given the possibility of ‘chameleon’ files that can be interpreted as multiple different types this is not necessarily watertight, so this is a ‘defense-in-depth’ measure at best.

Getting a web server to run a .jpeg file as PHP code could happen by:

1. being able to write to server configuration to associate .jpeg with the PHP handler. Typically this would happen because another vulnerable file upload feature allowed an attacker to write a `.htaccess` file in the same directory for Apache to pick up.
2. a PHP script with a Local File Inclusion security hole. Typically this would be code like:

   include("include/$variable");

where an attacker can get content into `$variable`, to point to something.jpeg. Generally `include`/`require` should never be used with variables unless those variables are explicitly limited to a few known-good values.

The other likely possibility if you have a load of malicious pages uploaded to your server is that your server login is compromised.